# How can I customize which Tabs show in the Tool shelf/panel?

Tags: interface, customization

I'd like to be able to add or remove some of the standard tabs on the Tools panel:

[image]

because if I shrink the tab area, the tab names become unreadable:

[image]

So, is there a way to remove some of the tabs that I never use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik the only way is to remove the tab in the python file of the UI toolbar. You can find this file in your blender folder. For me it is:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.XX\scripts\startup\bl_ui
```

The name of the file is : *space_view3d_toolbar.py*

For removing a tab you have to open this file with for example [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Then you have to find the tab that you want to remove. If you want to remove the *Relations* tab for the object mode, you can follow below example.

First you have to find the section of the code for the object-mode. You can find it with this header in comment:

```
# ********** default tools for object-mode ****************
```

Next you have to find the right tab. The name of the tab is in the `bl_category`, so for our example we have to find this:

```
bl_category = "Relations"
```

Now we can get rid of our tab, by either deleting the class of the tab, or by just making it a comment block like this:

[image]

You just have to put three quotes like this: `"""`, before and after the class that you want to comment out. I prefer to put the class in comment, so that you can recover it if you do something wrong.

Now you can save your file and restart Blender.