# 3D Viewport Sidebar tab ordering, hierarchy

Tags: 3d-view, interface

Is there any way to group, order, or create a hierarchy of sidebar tools, and vary these across the same 3D Viewport in more than one Workspace.  I especially focus on my plethora of tools in my 3D Viewport, but I could imagine this useful elsewhere to organize and reduce clutter.

The only way I can think of is to carefully enable each add-on in order of sidebar appearance (for vertical ordering), which would require a redo when I decide to enable another add-on with sidebar.

Is there at least some .ini file somewhere to be edited if blender offers no interface to order these?

In the following example, I would like not only to order my DAZ tools, but to create a parent that hides/reveals all of these.   Or in another use case to group all architectural tools.

It would also be nice to be able to launch a "DAZ version" of blender, and "architectural version" of blender, where the add-ons and sidebar tools appear based on session need.

[image]

Note that the Issue [How can I customize which Tabs show in the Tool shelf/panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9037/how-can-i-customize-which-tabs-show-in-the-tool-shelf-panel) shows how to sneak behind blender and edit a core python file, that only allows you to change order or remove CORE tabs -- is crude, inelegant and insufficient.

Comment: I find this future suggestion https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/9Hdbbc/ and another article that only adjusts the core tabs by editing a core PY file: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-change-the-tab-order-in-the-tool-shelf/618616

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize which Tabs show in the Tool shelf/panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9037/how-can-i-customize-which-tabs-show-in-the-tool-shelf-panel)

Comment: @PGmath thanks I am aware and my blenderartists.org link describes the same .py editing technique. this only describes how to move (or remove) core (non-add-on) tabs and there is no concept of hierarchy.